# Abrupt Author 1

Tags: riddle, knowledge

A cyclic event gave me birth and death days

The fourth wall has given me quite a bit of a faze

My real name was blockaded by a river of addiction

That's because the truth is stranger than fiction

Name the author

Hint 1

> The third line refers to where's this author's pen name comes from

Hint 2

> The fourth line references an opinion of the author, and it's no accident that I worded it like that

Comment: Just so you know, all 4 of these lines reference different things about the author, you must say all 4 references to the author for a full answer

Comment: Are the adjectives applying to the author or their books?

Comment: Sometimes it's a book, sometimes it's about the author. The 4th line is kind of in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> Mark Twain?

A cyclic event gave me birth and death days

> He was born 2 weeks after Halley's comet's closest approach to the Earth in 1835; and died one day after Halley's comet's closest approach to the Earth in 1910.

The fourth wall has given me quite a bit of a faze

> Mark Twain sometimes broke the fourth wall in his writings, most famously in The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn, where Huck references a previous Twain novel by saying, "You don't know about me without you have read a book by the name of The Adventures of Tom Sawyer; but that ain't no matter."

My real name was blockaded by a river of addiction

> Mark Twain's real name was Samuel Langhorne Clemens; the name "mark twain" was a phrase used to indicate that steamboats on the Mississippi River (a river known for its gambling boats) had two fathoms (each mark on the line was a fathom apart, and twain means second) of safe depth to work with. Thanks to @Kevorobin for the explanation of the origins of "mark twain"!!

That's because the truth is stranger than fiction

> Related to the Twain quote, "Truth is stranger than fiction, but it is because Fiction is obliged to stick to possibilities; Truth isn't."

Comment: ROT13 (V qba'g xabj vs guvf vf eryngr, ohg V ernq gung ur tbg uvf cra anzr sebz gur zrnfherzrag gung hfrq gb qrgrezvar fgrnzobngf fnsrgl bs gur Zvffvffvccv Evire.)

Comment: Thanks @Kevorobin! I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is

> Stephen King

The fourth wall has given me quite a bit of a faze

> In the Dark Tower series the protagonists, while hopping through parallel-worlds, meet Stephen King who recognizes them as the characters of his books

My real name was blockaded by a river of addiction

> I believe he was a cocain addict, and also sometimes used the pseudonym Richard Bachman

That's because the truth is stranger than fiction

> I think "It" is based on the true story of John Wayne Gacy

I'm still not getting the first line though...

Comment: Nope, but good guess

Comment: @XavierStanton Ok, now it's even more interesting :) Btw, I don't know why a part of my answer isn't hidden (I'm new here, probably didn't format my answer properly)

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Ernest Cline?

The cyclic event gave me birth and death days

> In Ready Player One, birth days might be when Parzival was on a roll for the gates. Death days might be when Parzival was in parties and got distracted from the jade key.

The fourth wall gave me quite a faze.

> The fourth gate or wall was the final battle, at that castle. The IOI people and the normal people clashed violently.

His real name was blockaded by a river of action.

> He tried to keep his real name secret and almost everyone didn't know his name (except for IOI and the school)

That's because the truth is stranger than fiction.

> The truth is reality and the fiction is the oasis. As it turns out the real world is falling apart, compared to the oasis

Comment: No it is not Ernest Cline